# Оптимизация кода (ternary + for)

Tags: java, коллекции, junit, тернарный-оператор

Решил задачку, но код все же надо оптимизировать. Не могу понять, как можно избавиться от тернарного в `return`, добавив его в цикл `for`(точнее во второе выражение цикла, чтобы он сразу работал и возвращал тот кусок, который мне необходим по заданию).

Само задание: Полученный массив чисел преобразовываем в список, затем все четные числа увеличиваем на один, после чего возвращаем кусок списка с 3 по 7 элементы.

Тест к заданию:

```java
@Test
    void task2() {
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(57, 23, 43, 95, 13),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(23, 15, 1, 56, 22, 42, 95, 13, 9)
        );
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(5, 7, 5, 7, 5),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7)
        );
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(5, -7, 15, 27, 5),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(0, -4, 7, 4, -7, 14, 27, 4, -27)
        );
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(15, 27, 5),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(0, 7, 4, 14, 27, 4)
        );
    }
```

Решение к заданию(код, который нужно оптимизировать):

```java
public static List<Integer> task2(Integer... array) {
        List<Integer> myArrays = Arrays.asList(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < myArrays.size(); i++) {
            if (myArrays.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                myArrays.set(i, myArrays.get(i) + 1);
            }
        }
        return myArrays.size() >= 8 ? myArrays.subList(3, 8) : myArrays.subList(3, myArrays.size());
    }
```

Comment: Как оптимизировать? Чтобы код быстрее выполнялся? Или тратилось меньше оперативной памяти?

Comment: если вам нужно вернуть только элементы с 3 по 7, зачем нужно все четные числа увеличивать, а не только те, которые находятся на позициях с 3 по 7?

Comment: как именно это реализовать? вдруг я получу на вход массив размерностью меньше 7, как в тесте?

Comment: а если ты получишь пустой массив? или null?

Comment: Допишу exception, это не проблема!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю следующие исправления(касается ошибок и оптимизации):

```
public static List<Integer> task2(Integer... array) {
    if(array.length < 7) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("need over 6 elements");
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list3to7 = new ArrayList<>(5);
    for(int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            array[i]++;
        }
        list3to7.add(array[i]);
    }
    return list3to7;
}
```

Comment: всё ещё неоптимально, т.к. перебирается весь входящий массив, когда нужно только [2:7)

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon "затем все четные числа увеличиваем на один" - дело в том, что Integer - объект, а не примитив. То есть, если где-то есть ссылка на него, и он четен, то значение по ссылке должно измениться.

Comment: Зачем, как вы думаете, он передает переменные, которые, по вашему, не должны использоваться? Тем более через ряд объектов, а не через массив - это я бы понял. Тем более передаются обертки. Не просто так ведь это.

Comment: а зачем кидать исключение, если элементов меньше 7? Судя по коду автора, это вполне нормальный случай. И зачем создавать лист на 7 элементов, если там будет не больше 5?

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar "дело в том, что Integer - объект, а не примитив. То есть, если где-то есть ссылка" - переданные инты не изменятся где-то еще

Comment: @Mikhaillonkin а вот с этим(заменить размерность на 5) согласен. Я забыл изначально поставить начальную размерность, а потом быстро поправил. По условию нам надо возвратить с 3 по 7 элементы. Значит мы должны пропустить первые 2 и вернуть последующие 5 - то есть переданных элементов должно быть не менее 7

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon согласен, значение Integer действительно нельзя изменять - в коде я просто создавал новый Integer. Поправил этот момент.